# Can't auto-complete the React component tag using tab in vscode?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Here is the code:

```html
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.17.5/babel.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/babel">
    function Child(props) {
      return <h2>{props.age}</h2>
    }
    function Parent(props) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{props.title}</h1>
          <Child age = '12'/>                               
        </div>
      )
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

In the returned body of function `Parent`, when I type `h1` and press `tab`, the `h1` turns into `<h1></h1>`. But this doesn't work when I type `Child` and press `tab`. The `Child` doesn't turn into a pair of tags. It seems the auto-complete has failed in this condition. How could I solve this problem? Installing an extension or changing some settings?

Btw, I now have installed the `Reacjs code snippet` extension and edited the setting like this:

```json
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript":"javascriptreact"
},
```

Comment: @evilmandarine No, I'm expecting `Child` to transform into `<Child>...</Child>` or just `<Child/>`. Anyway, it should be a tag here.

Comment: Ok. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an external JavaScript file and then import it to your HTML file like this :

```
<script src="./path/to/your/script.jsx"></script>
```

It's better if your file extension be .jsx, because VS Code treats that as a React app.

But this is not the suggested way to write react code.
I recommend to use `create-react-app` to create a React app:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Make sure to install node before.

Comment: Yes. In `.jsx` file it can work.  Typing `Child`  and pressing `tab` can make it transform into <Child>...</Child>. I just learn React recently and still haven't used building tools